# Positioning Dynamically created buttons

Tags: vb.net, button, dynamic, position

I am creating a program which creates a number of different buttons depending on how many entries are in an access database, the buttons are creating fine however they are not being positioned correctly, is there an easy way to govern where they will be positioned ?

The buttons are going to be used to send a string of information to the COM port the string will vary depending on which button is pressed as each button has a name on it that has been taken from the database.

they need to be arranged like a table 7 by 4 however the issue i am having is that i cannot make the button go onto the next line when the previous line is full

Comment: Are the buttons for a ladies or gents outfit? You will need to supply us with more information both context and what you have tried

Comment: @user2253029 I see from the edit history that you added the [tag:vb.net] tag. If so, and if your question is really about the positioning of buttons on a VB.NET form then please remove the [tag:ms-access] tag since the back-end data source is really not relevant to your question.

Comment: You're going to change the left and top property on each button you create, as far as the logic as to when to set top to a larger number (and reset left) when you go to a new line that's going to be specific to the form you're putting the buttons in.